# Visual Studio 2013 Light Switch Command Position Change

Tags: lightswitch-2013

Command bar in Visual Studio 2013 Light Switch is set to bottom of the page. How can I move it to the top of the page?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

On the Desktop Client Properties page, change the Shell from Cosmopolitan to Standard. The command bar should now be on the top and left justified. If you're want a different look, check out alternate Shells in the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=shell&f%5B1%5D.Value=shell&f%5B1%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=VSLS&f%5B0%5D.Type=VisualStudioVersion&f%5B0%5D.Text=Visual%20Studio%20LightSwitch&ac=4) or write an [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290138.aspx) yourself.

Comment: What about HTML Client page?

Comment: @KokiralaSudheer I'm not sure as I haven't used the HTML Client much. According to [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c3c2235c-22d1-472d-965a-006e0899d609/lightswitch-custom-control-command-bar-location-and-style?forum=lsextensibility) it's not possible but they do mention some workarounds. Hopefully some of those suggestions are helpful. And for the future, if your question is about the HTML client, it would be helpful if you mentioned that in your question.